# Trying to retrieve the files in a folder in Laravel from the app folder instead of storage

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to read the files inside a folder, I managed to read the files using the below code in the controller

```
 $files = Storage::files('public');
```

and displaying it using

```
return view('scripts.index')
            ->with('files', $files);
```

I get the following files found inside the storage/app/public folder:
[List of files inside folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofbH0.png)

However I want to read the content of the file inside the ProjectName/app folder.

I tried changing the config/filesystems.php file by changing the settings below to allow reading from another location other than the Storage folder but couldn't figure it out, this is the current code below as it is by default.

```
  'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I want to be able to read from here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRPES.png)

Comment: Try `$file = app_path("Jobs/examplejobs.php")`

Comment: it doesn't return an array, so in the view foreach i get 
`code Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Users/Sita/Sites/automator/resources/views/scripts/index.blade.php)' `